# logic connectives and symbols "most"

Tags: discrete-mathematics

"She went to at most two of the cities"

anwser:  ¬(a∧b∧c) or  ¬a∨¬b∨¬c

I don't really understand the logic here... For me, the answer means she went to none of those cities

Comment: The second answer is not a, "or" not b, "or" not c, which is correct for at most two. Hmm, but it doesn't cover one or none. It needs to add, or not ab, or not ac or not bc or not abc.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $a$ means "she went to city $A$" and so on.

Thus $¬(a∧b∧c)$ means "it is not true that she went at $A$ and $B$ and $C$".

This formula is TRUE when at least one of $a, b, c$ is FALSE.

And this is consistent with the fact that "She went to at most two of the cities": this means that she did not go to all three cities.

The part $¬a ∨ ¬b ∨ ¬c$ means "either she did not go to $A$ or she did not go to $B$ or she did not go to $C$.

This formula is FALSE when $a,b,c$ are all TRUE.

And this is consistent with the fact that "She went to at most two of the cities": the statement that she went to all three must be false.

Answer (score 1):

Re: your interpretation of the answer, I think you're switching "$\vee$" ("or") and "$\wedge$" ("and"). "She went to none of those cities" would be "$\neg a\wedge \neg b\wedge \neg c$."

As to the answer itself, "She went to at most *two* of the cities" is the same as "There was (at least) once city she *didn't* go to." That's why "$\neg a\vee\neg b\vee\neg c$" is the right answer: it's saying that she missed at least one city, which - since there are only three cities - is the same as saying that she went to at most two cities.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are confusing the symbols for "and" and "or."  $\vee$ means "or" and $\wedge$ means "and."  Therefore, $\neg(a\wedge b\wedge c)$ means "it is not the case that she went to all the cities."  Similarly, $\neg a \vee\neg b\vee\neg c$ means "there is at least one city she didn't visit."